# format (spaces btw words) issues with ssrs report exported to PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, format

I am currently running an ssrs report - the problem i am having is after exporting it to PDF - spaces between words are removed

e.g. - under the desc_column - This is a product...

after exporting to PDF it becomes - Thisisa product...

is there a solution for this?

i have tried using the replace functionwith no luck

Thanks!

Comment: Under normal conditions this should not occur. You haven't told us many details about what you've researched and debugged, nor what version of SSRS you use and if it's up to date? (In addition, it would help if you review your question and work a bit on readability: spelling, interpunction, general flow, and [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - you can edit your question at any time to improve it.)

Comment: I suspect the spaces aren't really missing, but that it's a font issue in the PDF. What happens if you cut and paste the text from the PDF? Are the spaces there?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following solution to resolve this issue

http://epmadvice.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/solution-spaces-removed-when-ssrs.html

Edited: 11/Mar/2015

The summary of the solution is to remove unwanted character (HEX ‘0B 20′) from your data. The following query will do the job

SELECT REPLACE(ColumnName, NCHAR(8203), '') AS ColumnName

Comment: Please consider including the solution in your answer. If that link ever goes dead, we won't be able to see the solution.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisLeyva . I have updated the answer to reflect actual solution